# Visual Studio creates new resource file

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working with Vistual Studio 2013 and Asp.net MVC 5 and when I updated a Labels.resx file a new file with the name Labels1.Designer.cs is created instead of update Labels.Designer.cs.

Here is a video of what I do:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_05Ut5G5sRMcmRSQk82UTU5bms/view

Any clue of what is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You likely already had a `Labels.Designer.cs` file existing in your filesystem that was not included in the project, so VS needed to generate a new filename so it wouldn't overwrite your existing file.

Do this:

1. Unload the project (Solution Explorer > %project% > Unload Project)
2. Delete any designer-generated files for your Labels resource file from your filesystem
3. Edit your project in text-mode (Solution Explorer > %project% > Edit Project) and remove all references to the designer-generated label files. You'll also find additional `<DependsOn>` elements, ensure they're gone.
4. Reload the project (Solution Explorer > %project% > Reload Project)
5. Open and re-save the Labels resource file, and the designer-generated file will be recreated.